# OpenLayers: Unit conversion in Projection

Tags: openlayers

I have a dataset in millimeters, but my projection is in meters.
Does anyone now how to fix this??

I tried '+units=mm' in the projection but that has no effect.

Thanks,

BR.

Comment: Divide by 1000.

Comment: I'm a lazy guy. I dont want to parse my geometries. The projection should be aware of this, that is why I tried to set units=mm.

Answer (score 0):

nailed it.

Add "+units=mm +to_meter=0.001" to your projection definition.

Second problem arised: reverse axis.

Add "+axis=neu" to your def.

All's well.